# How to read data only between two lines in python using numpy or pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a datafile like this:

```
# column 1 is the angle of incidence (degrees)
# column 2 is the wavelength (microns)
# column 3 is the transmission probability
# column 4 is the reflection probability
      14.2000     0.300000  0.01     0.999920
      14.2000     0.301000  0.02     0.999960
      14.2000     0.302000  0.03     0.999980
      14.2000     0.303000  0.04     0.999980
      14.2000     0.304000  0.06     0.999980
      14.2000     0.305000  0.08     0.999970
      14.2000     0.306000  0.2     0.999950
      14.2000     0.307000  0.4     0.999910
      14.2000     0.308000  0.8     0.999860
      14.2000     0.309000  0.9     0.999960
      14.2000     0.310000  0.8     0.999990
      14.2000     0.311000  0.4     0.999980
      14.2000     0.312000  0.2     0.999960
      14.2000     0.313000  0.06     0.999940
      14.2000     0.314000  0.03     0.999930
      14.2000     0.315000  0.02     1.00000
      14.2000     0.316000  0.01     1.00000
```

Required output file `output.csv` is this:

```
# column 1 is the angle of incidence (degrees)
# column 2 is the wavelength (microns)
# column 3 is the transmission probability
# column 4 is the reflection probability
      14.2000     0.304000  0.06     0.999980
      14.2000     0.305000  0.08     0.999970
      14.2000     0.306000  0.2     0.999950
      14.2000     0.307000  0.4     0.999910
      14.2000     0.308000  0.8     0.999860
      14.2000     0.309000  0.9     0.999960
      14.2000     0.310000  0.8     0.999990
      14.2000     0.311000  0.4     0.999980
      14.2000     0.312000  0.2     0.999960
      14.2000     0.313000  0.06     0.999940
      14.2000     0.314000  0.03     0.999930


      # conditions are: 
      # output first element of column3 >= 0.05   i.e. 0.06
      # output last  element of column3  < 0.05   i.e. 0.03

      # for the second may be we need to get the index of second 0.06 and 
      #     get the value of next index.
```

How can we do so in python pandas or numpy?

My initial attempt is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
# Author    : Bhishan Poudel 
# Date      : June 16, 2016 


# Imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#==============================================================================
# read in a file
infile = 'filter_2.txt'
colnames = ['angle', 'wave','trans', 'refl']
print('{} {} {} {}'.format('\nreading file : ', infile, '','' ))
df = pd.read_csv(infile,sep='\s+', header = None,skiprows = 0,
                 comment='#',names=colnames,usecols=(0,1,2,3))

print(df)

# find value of wavelength just above 0.05
print("\n")
df         = df[(df['trans'] >=  0.05) ]
print(df)
```

Some similar links are following:
[How to read between 2 specific lines in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591999/how-to-read-between-2-specific-lines-in-python)

Comment: Rest assured, there is an answer that will get you what you want.  But you need to state the requirements more clearly.  As you've specified it, it is ambiguous.

Comment: How do you anticipate applying these conditions?  `column 3 >= 0.05 and column 3 < 0.05` results in nothing.  `column 3 >= 0.05 or column 3 < 0.05` is everything.  Why are the second or third elements not included?  The third element has the same value 0.03 as the last.  What differentiates it such that it is excluded?

Comment: @piRSquared The problem was given to me. Now the question is not why to do this, but it is how to do this? may be the second condtion needs to get the index number of the 0.06 add 1 to the index and get the next value, but i am still learning how to do this?

Comment: That may be it.  I'd report back to who ever gave this to you because it may be that they've made a mistake.  I'll update my answer to include one more.

Comment: @piRSquared you are the most welcomed person in the world, and the savior! I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Is it possible they meant all rows above and below those that satisfy the requirement?

Comment: @piRSquared if we can get the index of last value of the answer, then we may get the next element to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd skip pandas or numpy altogether

```
fo = open('filter_3.txt', 'w')
with open('filter_2.txt', 'r') as fi:
    line = fi.readline()
    while line:
        split = line.split()
        if (split[0] == '#') or (float(split[2]) >= 0.027):
            print line,
            fo.write(line)

        line = fi.readline()

fo.close()

# column 1 is the angle of incidence (degrees)
# column 2 is the wavelength (microns)
# column 3 is the transmission probability
# column 4 is the reflection probability
      14.2000     0.302000  0.028     0.999980
      14.2000     0.303000  0.030     0.999980
      14.2000     0.304000  0.032     0.999980
      14.2000     0.305000  0.030     0.999970
      14.2000     0.306000  0.028     0.999950
```

---

#### New code to include one more line

```
fo = open('filter_3.txt', 'w')
with open('filter_2.txt', 'r') as fi:
    new_line = fi.readline()
    old_line = None
    while new_line:
        split_new = new_line.split()
        if old_line is not None:
            split_old = old_line.split()

        cond0 = False if old_line is None else (split_old[0] == '#')
        cond1 = split_new[0] == '#'
        cond2 = float(split_new[2]) >= 0.05
        cond3 = False if old_line is None else (float(split_old[2]) >= 0.05)

        if (cond1 or cond2) or (cond3 and not cond0):
            print new_line,
            fo.write(new_line)
            printed_old = True

        old_line = new_line
        new_line = fi.readline()

fo.close()

# column 1 is the angle of incidence (degrees)
# column 2 is the wavelength (microns)
# column 3 is the transmission probability
# column 4 is the reflection probability
      14.2000     0.304000  0.06     0.999980
      14.2000     0.305000  0.08     0.999970
      14.2000     0.306000  0.2     0.999950
      14.2000     0.307000  0.4     0.999910
      14.2000     0.308000  0.8     0.999860
      14.2000     0.309000  0.9     0.999960
      14.2000     0.310000  0.8     0.999990
      14.2000     0.311000  0.4     0.999980
      14.2000     0.312000  0.2     0.999960
      14.2000     0.313000  0.06     0.999940
      14.2000     0.314000  0.03     0.999930
```

Comment: First thanks. Then, I tried this code with updated question with slightly new data, it has small problem, it does not print last line just below 0.05, (i.e. 0.03)

Comment: Awe, I'll fix that.

Comment: 0.03 >= 0.05 is not `True`

Comment: yes, the requirements are tricky.  You're asking for "column 3 is between 0.05 and 0.05" which is impossible.  I have to jump to conclusions to get at what you mean.  So I use, `df[(df['trans'] >=  0.05)` to help me understand what you mean.  In this case, 0.03 is not >= 0.05 and would not show up.  Either way, the technique is the same.  Just read the file directly and write the same exact line if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: sorry for ambiguous question, I have updated the question!

Comment: WOW, unbelievable!, I thought it was almost impossible. I am learning python from your answers. You are amazing!

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to maintain the appearance of the written file (i.e., the line spacing is the same), then you'll likely need to keep the original file's contents.

```
from io import StringIO
contents = open(infile).read()

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(contents), sep='\s+', header = None,skiprows = 0,
                 comment='#',names=colnames,usecols=(0,1,2,3))
allowed_indices = df.query('trans >= 0.027').index.values

content_lines = np.array(contents.split('\n'))
num_comments =  len([l for l in contents_lines if l.startswith('#')])
comment_and_allowed_indices = np.append(np.array(range(num_comments)),
                                        allowed_indices + num_comments)
```

Then you'll just need to write the original contents to a file. They can be indexed via:

```
content_lines[comment_and_allowed_indices]
```

Comment: Thanks. However small bug, The last line should be 14.2000     0.314000  0.03     0.999930

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can do it this way:

```
In [51]: df[df.loc[df.trans >= 0.05, 'trans'].index.min() : df.loc[df.trans >= 0.05, 'trans'].index.max() + 1]
Out[51]:
    angle   wave  trans     refl
4    14.2  0.304   0.06  0.99998
5    14.2  0.305   0.08  0.99997
6    14.2  0.306   0.20  0.99995
7    14.2  0.307   0.40  0.99991
8    14.2  0.308   0.80  0.99986
9    14.2  0.309   0.90  0.99996
10   14.2  0.310   0.80  0.99999
11   14.2  0.311   0.40  0.99998
12   14.2  0.312   0.20  0.99996
13   14.2  0.313   0.06  0.99994
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: Thanks. The last line required was 14 14.2     0.314  0.03     0.99993